# Finite sum inequality

Tags: calculus

I was wondering if the following inequality was true.

$\sum_i |x_i||y_i|\leq \sqrt{\sum_i|x_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_i|y_i|^2}$

Squaring both sides yields

$|x_1||y_1|(\sum_i |x_i||y_i|)+\dots + |x_n||y_n|(\sum_i |x_i||y_i|)=(\sum_i |x_i||y_i|)^2\leq \sum_i|x_i|^2\sum_i|y_i|^2=|x_1|^2(\sum_i|y_i|^2)+|x_2|^2(\sum_i|y_i|^2)+\dots+|x_n|^2(\sum_i|y_i|^2)$.

However, this does not really help, because I cannot say anything useful about the values of the sums. It is known that all sums converge, since they are all finite.

Comment: It is true, it is called [the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#%E2%84%9Dn_-_n-dimensional_Euclidean_space).

Comment: However for Cauchy-Schwarz we have 
$|\sum_i x_i y_i|$. That is not the case here, we have the absolute value inside the summation. and by the triangle inequality that is automatically bigger than $|\sum_i x_i y_i|$. So how does Cauchy-Schwarz relate to this version?

Comment: If you apply Cauchy-Schwarz to the element-wise absolute value of the vectors, then you end up with this inequality.

Comment: I am sorry, but this does not make sense. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that in the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality $|\sum_{i} u_i v_i| \leq \sqrt{\sum_i u_i^2}\sqrt{\sum_i v_i^2}$, if you substitute $|x_i|$ for $u_i$ and $|y_i|$ for $v_i$, you end up with the inequality that you have.

Comment: The absolute value can be removed on the left hand side, because it will already be positive.

Comment: Ah! That makes total sense. Thanks!